# Issue showing an image from the database in a web page using asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have been following this page: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-images-from-SQL-Server-Database-in-ASP.Net-GridView-control.aspx

My problem is that I cannot get the images to show on the page. I am connecting to the database, I am getting the binary, it is even making an image out of it but it just will not display on the page.

If I run the .aspx file it downloads the image from the database in (in my case) tif format no problem. But when I try to display the image on the web page it just doesnt work.

Im not even sure where to look anymore for why it isnt working.

If anyone has any ideas where i might be going wrong that'd be great. Cheers.

### Default.aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns = "false" Font-Names = "Arial" Caption = "Using ImageControl" >
<Columns>
    <%--<asp:BoundField DataField = "DealerID" HeaderText = "Image Name" />--%>

    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Image ID="SignatureSnippetData" Height = "100" Width = "100" runat="server" ImageURL = 'ImageHandler.aspx' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

### Default.aspx.cs

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int sigID = 3254;

    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select SignatureSnippetData FROM ReferenceSignatures WHERE SignatureID =" + sigID + "", cn);
    SqlDataAdapter myAdapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = cn;
    try
    {
        cn.Open();
        myAdapter1.SelectCommand = cmd;
        myAdapter1.Fill(dt);
        GridView2.DataSource = dt;
        GridView2.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        cn.Close();
        myAdapter1.Dispose();
        cn.Dispose();
        dt.Dispose();
    }        
}
```

}

### ImageHandler.aspx.cs

```
public partial class ImageHandler : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    string strQuery = "Select SignatureSnippetData FROM ReferenceSignatures WHERE SignatureID = 3254";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = con;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
        sda.Fill(dt);
    }
    catch
    {
        dt = null;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
        sda.Dispose();
        con.Dispose();
    }

    if (dt != null)
    {
        Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])dt.Rows[0]["SignatureSnippetData"];
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.ContentType = "image/TIF";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=file.Tif");
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why the `Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=file.Tif");`?

Comment: Well, Ill level with you. this is my first time doing asp.Net and it was there in the tutorial so I kept it. Though I found it handy to know that it does seem to change the binary into an image.

Comment: What browser are you using. it seems that not all browsers support .tif

Comment: Using Chrome. Just tried on IE11 too. Same thing

Comment: Chrome does not support .tif. And I tried to open a .tiff file from my computer in IE11 and it did not worked. So i guess IE11 does not support it either.

Comment: Thanks. It was to do with format. image/tif doesnt work on either. So I tried image/gif and it works on IE but not Chrome. But thats all I need. Cheers for the help.